# How to display a list of objects separated with commas in the console?

Tags: angular

I want to display my data like this in the console:

```
  [
    {id: 1, text: 'Sentence 1'},
    {id: 2, text: 'Sentence 2'},
    {id: 3, text: 'Sentence 3'},
    {id: 4, text: 'Sentenc4 '}
 ]
```

But when I do this:

```
this.requestForCreate.push({"id":v.id,"text":this.text})
```

The console shows something like this:

```
0: {id: "38730291789", text: "Available"}
1: {id: "38730291790", text: "Available"}
2: {id: "38730291791",  text: "Available"}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Not enough information here to determine what is going on. I think you'll just have to step through it with a debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the same result, it's just the difference in displaying it in console.

You will get your desired result

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.requestForCreate))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your Javascript level, but those are two different things.

The first one is a Javascript array containing objects. Plain, simple, like it should be.

The second one is the log of your console. This is how Chrome decides to show you your data. This isn't your object, this is a view of your object.

You can have a different view if you try

```
console.table(myObject);
```

Instead of

```
console.log(myObject);
```

But in both cases, you will have your object defined as the first one you posted.